# How to import / use typings into angular 2 component

Tags: angular, npm, leaflet, angular-cli

I am really trying to understand how to correctly import a dependency into a component.

I have installed the `Leaflet` library and its typings into the project (packages.json snippet):

```
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.0.38"
...
    "leaflet": "^1.0.2"
```

`@types/leaflet/index.d.ts` exports:

```
declare module 'leaflet' {
    export = L;
}
```

In my component file, get complaints for all:

```
import leaflet from 'leaflet';
//import L from 'leaflet';

export class AppComponent {
  mymap = leaflet.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
}
```

> Module ''leaflet'' has no default export.at line 3 col 8

What's the correct import statement? (I admit this is a big hole in my understanding of the angular cli / webpack / typescript / black hole)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either import all of the exports like this:

```
import * as L from "leaflet";

let m = L.map(...);
```

Or you can import them individually like this:

```
import { map } from "leaflet";

let m = map(...);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is that pulling straight from the raw leaflet, is it even taking into account the @types at all?

Comment: It's using `@types/leaflet` - version 1.0.38 - as per your question. I don't see any TypeScript definitions in the `leaflet` package itself. If it's still not working for you, you might want to include your `tsconfig.json` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet doesn't seem to be compatible with ES2015 modules. Try this syntax:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet'
```

And use it like this:

```
let marker = L.marker(...)
```